# How to calculate improved probability of getting a correct answer through replication

Tags: probability, independence, sample

A mapping inspector checks a route to determine if it is a footpath (FP). Independently, another inspector checks the same route. And so on. The process is replicated N times. The results of all the inspectors are collated and the decision as to whether or not to represent the route as a FP or not done by majority decision of the inspectors. How much more reliable (probability of correctly identifying the footpath) are 2, 3, 4 ...N independent inspections compared to 1 inspection.
Of course the inspectors could be useless in which case individual assessments might only have a probability of 50% of being correct.  Given their training they are likely to be better than this.

Comment: Unless you can quantify "Given their training they are likely to be better than this." including whether some inspectors are better than others in their assessments, there is not much that can be said other than the probability is greater than $\frac 12$.